# React: render an array where some elements are regular strings, others are <Link> components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have a JSON object with a property `content` which is an array.

Some elements in this array are regular strings, and some of them are `<Link/>` components from `react-router-dom`. eg:
`["String1 ", "String2 ", "<Link to='/path'/>path</Link> ", etc]`

At the moment react is rendering the literal string `<Link to.../>` where I want to render the Link component.

The row that is rendering the object is: `<Row style={{ cursor: 'text' }}>{content}</Row>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs convert html string to jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx

Comment: @mohituprim i think it might answer it but im not sure how to implement it, ive change my `<Row` object to `<Row dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}} style={{ cursor: 'text' }}/>` but it hasnt changed what is rendered.

Comment: can you create demo in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ckmrd

Comment: Do you have the ability to actually pass the link component instead of representing it as a string?  Because that would be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In your array you have the React Link element encapsulated by quotes. Anything put in quotes JavaScript will treat as the primitive string. What you are trying to do is probably render the React component with JSX. Simply remove the quotes (and also it seems there is an extra / after '/path'): path. This JSX code then gets converted to JavaScript at compilation and should render the component.

Comment: I dont put the quotes there myself, i am actually replacing the old content which is a string, splitting it with `str.split(' ')` and then conditionally replacing elements if they start with a '#' with a `<Link>` component.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeing this post in the future, I ended up using `react-string-replace` to replace strings in my content with components which works without having to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.