# How to use innerHTML for Accordion (PrimeReact)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

In my React project, I am using the PrimeReact library to display some Accordions. But I need to create them dynamically and this is the current result:

[image]

As you see, the html tags are also shown in the answers of the faqs. I tried using `innerHTML` and `dangerouslySet...` but to no success.

Here is my relevant code:

```
createAccordions = () => {
    const allFAQs = this.state.allFAQs;
    let accordions = [];

    for (const faq of allFAQs) {
        const accordion = <AccordionTab header={faq.question} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `<p>yo man</p>`}}></AccordionTab>;
        accordions.push(accordion);
    }

    return accordions
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="component">
            <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{this.state.pageTitle}</h1>

            <div className="p-grid">
                
                <div className="p-col-3">

                </div>

                <div className="p-col-6">
                    <Accordion>
                        {this.createAccordions()}
                    </Accordion>
                </div>


                <div className="p-col-3">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I properly set the innerhtml for the accordions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS convert HTML string to JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx)

Comment: @GrafiCode Sadly not in this case. The dangerouslySetInnerHTML didnt work for me in this case.

Comment: Then no content is shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/components/accordion/Accordion.js#L154) and found that the library tries to render the children you pass to it. I see you tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but set it on the `AccordionTab` itself instead of the child passed into it.

I set up a quick [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-forked-tt0sl) on CodePen. I passed in a `div` container to set the innerHTML on, and it seems to work!

```
<AccordionTab header="Demo">
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<ul><li>I am HTML</li></ul>" }}></div>
</AccordionTab>
```