# Convert HTML string to JSX string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is there is a tool or quick way to convert arbitrary HTML **strings** to valid JSX **strings**? And by string, I mean an actual string.

```
const htmlString = "<button class="foo" onclick="..." >Hello World</button>"
const jsxString = htmlStringToJsxString(htmlString)
console.log(jsxString)
```

And my desired output:

`"<button className="foo" onClick="..." >Hello World</button>"`

[I'm not trying to parse HTML then render JSX, nor am I injecting HTML into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx). I specifically need to convert an HTML string to the conventions of JSX (camel-casing attributes, replacing "class" with "className", etc).

Comment: You'd get a lot better help if you answered: why?

Comment: ....but I suppose there's always: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: How deep does the translation need to go? Do you need the capability to transform ANY html string to JSX, or is there a limited use case here?