# p tag is removing new line character in string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a string that contains a new line character. For example:

```
const myString = `hello\nstring`
```

I am then trying to dispaly this string in a functional component, which is wrapped around a `p` tag. For example:

```
export default function App() {
  const testString = "hi\nString";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{testString}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For some reason, the `p` tag simply displays "hello string" on one line when I'd like for it to be displayed across two lines. Is there a way that I can stop the `p` tag from removing the new-line character from within the string?

The following Code Sandbox contains the executable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-allen-ehrsd8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This isn't related to React.  HTML layout ignores linebreaks and collapses whitespace, so you can format your HTML code without messing up the layout.  If you want a line break you need to convert the `\n` to a `<br>` ,or wrap the text in a `<pre>`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried to wrap the text in both `<br>` or `<pre>`, but those are then inserted as literal strings.

Comment: _That_ part is related to react. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because new lines and white spaces are collapsed in browser by default. You do not need any JavaScript for this, just add following line in your stylesheet -

```
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted this answer as it's more elegant in my opinion than the other working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `<br/>` code to break the line.? Please check code as given below-

```
export default function App() {
  const testString = "hi<br/>String";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{testString}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried with a `<br>` tag but that just inserts it as a literal string.

Comment: can you share whole code next to comment.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split` method whenever `\n` is found inside your code to enter new line

```
  function NewlineText(props) {
  const text = props.text;
  const newText = text.split('\n').map(str => <p>{str}</p>);
  
  return newText;
}

export default function App() {
  const testString = `hi\nString`;
 return (
    <div className="App">
<p><NewlineText text={testString} /></p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This [site](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newline-in-react-string-solved/68484) might clear your any remaining doubts.