# React Display rich text

Tags: reactjs, richtext

Simple question, I'm actualy fetching rich text from strapi and want to display it inside a div right after, but the text is just normal text after putting it in,I want it to stick to its format that I had on strapi, how can I do that ?

It seem to be possible using Markdown, I don't know why but after fetching using axios my strapi contentful or dangerouslySetInnerHTML doesnt work

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS convert HTML string to JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx)

Comment: What is the format of the rich text. Is it HTML or something like Markdown?

Comment: Didnt worked, and like it's name is suggesting it is not secured thats why I was searching for an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem to be possible using Markdown, I don't know why but after fetching using axios my strapi contentful or dangerouslySetInnerHTML doesnt work but markdown package worked fine !

Comment: how does the markdown page work how did you use it?

Comment: please i am facing the same problem as you, so please explain in detail on how you used markdown to overcome it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ayex from what i remember I've done something similar to this : https://retool.com/blog/react-markdown-component-the-easy-way-to-create-rich-text
I can't confirm I stoped doing web dev for a while (doing software and games for Since 2023)

Comment: here is the questions you are talking about markdown, mine is rich text format?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78086034/how-to-convert-rich-text-format-to-display-in-react

Comment: @ayex Markdown let you put rich text in html in react

Comment: but it does not format it correctly, from the encoded format

Comment: @ayex you probably doesnt have the same format than me, Strapi's Rich Text format was compatible with Markdown for me

Comment: well i am having microsoft's C# encoded