# how to convert rich text format to display in react

Tags: reactjs, rtf

I have rich text format fetched from mssql database and i want to display it correctly in my react application, and can't seem to find any library and also i need a library with typescript(type safed),any ideas.
here is how RTF looks:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\
fcharset0 Verdana;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}
{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Trebuchet MS;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\f0\fs20 
Sharp costophrenic angles bilaterally . \par \par 
\pard\ltrpar\sl360\slmult1 There is no cardiac enlargement. \par There is 
no active lung parenchymal lesion. \par \f1\fs28 \par \pard\ltrpar\f0\fs20
 Impression:Normal chest xray\f2\fs20 \par }
```

Comment: have you try?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtf-parser

Comment: yes it is not type safe so typescript yells at me and it is not maintained now

Comment: and also I need to do it on the front end, the library is for backend