# Unable to process Azure Functions Html response with React - Expo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-functions, expo

**Disclaimer: I am new to JS so this problem is probably pretty simple to solve, but I have consulted all resources and stack overflow posts I could find online on the subject**

This is probably something simple that's missing but I haven't been able to debug this problem :

I want to connect an Azure Function API to a React app, but I am unable to process the Html Response, which makes my await functions hang.

Here is the very simple Azure functions API code :

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import json


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')


    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'recommendations': [1,2,3,4,5]
            }),
        mimetype="application/json"
        );
```

And here is my React based app (running with Expo) :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedUser: 0,
    step: 0,
    recommendations: 1
  };

  goToStep0 = async () => {
    this.setState({ step: 0, recommendations: 1 });
  };

  goToStep1 = async () => {
    const { data: rec } = await axios.get(config.API_URL);
    //const rec = await axios.get(config.API_URL);
    // const options = {method: "GET"};
    // var rec;

    // fetch(config.API_URL,options)
    // .then(data => {rec = data.recommendations;});

    
    this.setState({ step: 1, recommendations: rec });
  };
```

The Azure function **is receiving input and returns a successful answer everytime**.

What I have tried :

- Changing the the Azure function app to return a string
- Trying to get the request with fetch
- Removing async and running a more old school request :

```
var rec;
fetch(config.API_URL)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
rec = data
});
```

- Probably at least 10 other things I have forgotten (I have wasted more than 4 hours on this...)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Edit : Below is the code for the rendering part of the app (text is in French) :

```
    render() {
        if (!config.API_URL) {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image
                style={{ resizeMode: "center", width: 450, height: 150 }}
                source={require("./assets/icon-flat.png")}
              />
              <Text style={{ color: "red", margin: 20 }}>
                L'app n'est pas configurée correctement. Mettez à jour le fichier
                config.json comme indiqué dans le README.
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              style={{ resizeMode: "center", width: 450, height: 150 }}
              source={require("./assets/icon-flat.png")}
            />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, padding: 20, textAlign: "center" }}>
              Choisissez votre profil afin de recevoir des recommendations de
              lecture personnalisées : {this.state.recommendations.toString()}
              Quel est mon état : {this.state.step}
            </Text>
            <Picker
              style={{ height: 200, width: "80%", margin: 30 }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedUser}
              onValueChange={value => this.setState({ selectedUser: value })}
            >
              {[...Array(10000).keys()].map(e => (
                <Picker.Item key={e} label={`User ${e}`} value={e} />
              ))}
            </Picker>
            <Button title="Se connecter" onPress={this.goToStep1} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the problem. The code was not problematic as much as the fact that I was using an old version of react and axios.

With the newest version, I am unable to send requests to **localhost** but I managed to get responses after deploying the application.

I have "deployed" my Azure function API to the internet using Ngrok which allows me to handle requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the callback function on Axios call like this:

```
  axios.get(config.API_URL)
  .then(res => {
    if (res) {
     console.log("Data fetched: ", res)
      // do stuff
    }
    else {
      // do stuff
    }
  }).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
  })
```

Like you did with fetch

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your answer (I had already tried something similar before) but it is the same result : the React app freezes after I run the goToStep1 function and I never receive a response

Comment: Where do you run goToStep1 function? Looks like the app freezes because of too many renderers.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I have updated my main post with the rendering part of the app. I doubt this is the issue though because when I pass in a static recommendation value it renders fine. What really seems to bug is getting the html response from my azure function API

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277723/10013076