# HTML tags in i18next translation files in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I'm using [i18next](http://i18next.com/) in a project and can't get around including html tags in translation files and having them properly rendered.

An example of my `.json` translation file:

```
"en": {
  "product": {
    "header": "Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>"
  }
}
```

There is an [excellent answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038458/html-tags-in-i18next-translation), but relating to JQuery. I'm not using JQuery, my project is React and here is the setup that I have:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import en from 'locales/en';

i18next.
  init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: false,
    resources: en,
    debug: false,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

export default i18next.t.bind(i18next);
```

In component I have:

```
import t from 'i18n';

t('product.header')
```

Html that I want:

```
Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>
```

Html I'm getting:

```
Welcome, &lt;strong&gt;User!&lt;/strong&gt
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Petr Gaxarov - Please share solution if you found one.

Comment: I am also facing same issue @Petr Gaxarov Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 15):

Don't put the HTML tags in the translation. It's a bad idea anyway. *Separation of concerns* guys will be all whiny about it.

Use the `<Trans>` component if **react-i18next** https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Do like so:

```js
// Component.js

<Trans>Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>, here's your <strong>broom</strong></Trans>
```

And the corresponding translation file:

```js
// your locales/starwars_en.js file

translations: {
  "Welcome, <1>User!</1>, here's your <3>broom</3>": "Welcome, <1>young padawan!</1>, here's your <3>light saber</3>",
}
```

These numbers *<1>* and *<3>* will strike you as random but wait for it:

```js
Trans.children = [
  'Welcome, ',                        // index 0
  '<strong>User!</strong>'            // index 1
  ', please don't be ',               // index 2
  '<strong>weak</strong>',            // index 3
  ' unread messages. ',               // index 4
]
```

**SIDE NOTE (Can be considered a hack but saves tons of time):** The guys at react.i18next.com, don't have this in their docs, but you can use the base language as a **key** (English in this case). It saves you time, not to double translate like they showed in their docs and I quote:

```js
// Component file

import React from 'react';
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next'

function MyComponent({ person, messages }) {
  const { name } = person;
  const count = messages.length;

  return (
    <Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
      Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
    </Trans>
  );
}
```

```js
// translation file

"userMessagesUnread": "Hello <1>{{name}}</1>, you have {{count}} unread message. <5>Go to message</5>.",
"userMessagesUnread_plural": "Hello <1>{{name}}</1>, you have {{count}} unread messages.  <5>Go to messages</5>.",
```

Anyway "Kudos!" to the i18next team! You are awesome, guys!

Here - [go nuts](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#how-to-get-the-correct-translation-string)!

Comment: This library makes absolutely no sense. Reading the translations file example above makes no sense on how that could conceptually work. It's extremely esoteric beyond basic examples and the documentation acts like it isn't

Comment: this solution is no longer valid (if has ever been due to `{{name}}` which reports `Objects are not valid as a React child`), the one from @Jan Turoň works better

Answer (score 15):

Since `react-i18next@11.6.0`, you can use tags inside your translation string and replace it with `components` prop in `Trans` component or `t` property from `useTranslation` hook:

https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-react-components

Example of usage:

```js
<Trans
  i18nKey="myKey" // optional -> fallbacks to defaults if not provided
  defaults="hello <italic>beautiful</italic> <bold>{{what}}</bold>" // optional defaultValue
  values={{ what: 'world'}}
  components={{ italic: <i />, bold: <strong /> }}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah that good solution but if our json file itself has this kind of string `Welcome, &lt;strong&gt;User!&lt;/strong&gt ` then it will show `Welcome, &lt;strong&gt;User!&lt;/strong&gt ` on UI side.

Comment: So, is there any way to convert &lt; to < and &gt; to > ???

Comment: @DhavalParmar Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: in case it throws `Nothing returned from render`, it might be missing `i18n` instance it automatically obtains from `I18nContext` so you have to pass it to `Trans` component via `i18n` prop

Answer (score 6):

not a problem of react-i18next - you just can't add html into a react element. react will safe you from xss vulnerability and escape the content:

more detail and possible solution: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

but be aware if you put user content there not escaped you open your site to xss attacks.

more secure reading the react-i18next readme: 
https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next#interpolate-component

which makes you split content

so the "best" solution - at least what we do - is using markdown in the translations and use eg: https://github.com/acdlite/react-remarkable to convert that to formatted content.

Comment: With v4.4.0 we added a new component to make it simple to include react components into your translations https://react.i18next.com/components/trans-component.html

Comment: the link you posted is broken

Comment: I liked the suggestion to use `react-remarkable`, and I've shared [`i18n-react-app`](https://github.com/mogsdad/i18n-react-app) on GitHub to show how to modify the "Create React App" boilerplate to combine i18next and Markdown. I chose [`react-markdown`](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) instead because `react-remarkable` doesn't appear to be maintained anymore.

Comment: @jamuhl The link is https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use the property [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/). This lets you use HTML in your JSON that will be rendered in the tag.

> Note that you can't have both, this property and children

Example of usage

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t(`users_desc`) }} />
```

in the json you can write something like this

```
{
...
"users_desc": "Users  are <b> Amazing </b>"
...
}
```

This will render a tag

with a tag  as child.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use `Trans` without converting every tag to number tag:

```json
"en": {
  "product": {
    "header": "Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>"
  }
}
```

"strong" tags in translation file will be replaced with components' the value of "strong" key

```html
<Trans i18nKey="en.product.header" components={{ strong: <strong /> }} />
```

The result is "Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>" as html as you expected.

Answer (score -3):

First you need to write your json file like this:

```
"en":{
   "Welcome":"Welcome",
   "User":"User"
}
```

Then write your HTML code as follows:

```
<header>{t('Welcome')},<strong>{t('User')}!<strong>
<header>
```

Comment: <header>t('Welcome')},<strong>{t('User')! <strong><header>