# how to make HTML tag work in JSON i18next translation?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-redux, react-i18next

An HTML tag  is displayed as a text, in i18n translation. How can I fix it?
And also 'deviceLimit' property is not displayed.

tsx file:

```
const DeviceLimitTooltip: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const { classes, deviceLimit, isDeviceLimitReached, children, style } = props;
  const [t] = useTranslation();

  if (isDeviceLimitReached) {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        title={
          <React.Fragment>            
            {t("devices.freePlan.lastDevice", {deviceLimit: deviceLimit})}            
            <Link color={'secondary'} href={SUPPORT_CONTACT_US} target={'_blank'}>
              {t('devices.freePlan.contactUs')}
            </Link>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        placement="top"
        interactive
        classes={{ popper: classes.popper, tooltip: classes.tooltip }}
      >
        <span style={style}>{children}</span>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }

  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

translation.json:

```
 "freePlan": {      
      "lastDevice": "You've reached <strong>your limit of {{deviceLimit}} devices</strong> under the current free plan. To add more devices, please, ",
      "contactUs": "contact us."     
    }
```

here is screenshot how it looks now
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you'll use the Trans component: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

More information can be found in this stackoverflow question: [HTML tags in i18next translation files in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836369/html-tags-in-i18next-translation-files-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Trans, useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
```

in component:

```
<Trans t={t} i18nKey="lastDevice" values={{ deviceLimit: deviceLimit}}  />
```