# React Unknown Prop Warning

Tags: reactjs, redux, warnings, react-redux, react-router-redux

I was trying to render a DOM element with a prop but my attempt is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property.

So I started researching for a solution and I found this source from [React Warning Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html). However, although well explained, I have a deeper problem that will involve a deeper solution therefore.

As an example of code I will introduce the `ExampleContainer` method:

```
export let ExampleContainer = (props) => {

    return (
        <DetailsContainer tabs={props.tabs} activeTab={props.activeTab}>
            {props.children}
        </DetailsContainer>
    )
}
```

Now I have my `mapStateToProps` receiving a `state`that I beleave is well implemented and I will bring it here just to context my problem:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    i18n: state.i18n,
    activeTab : state.example.activeTab
  }
}
```

Finally, the problem is inside my `mergeProps` where I have this `tabs` source giving me the problem and more specificly inside it on the `i18n` attribute:

```
const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  return Object.assign({}, ownProps, {
    tabs: [
      {
        'onClick' : dispatchProps.goToExampleOptionA,
        'key' : 'ExampleOptionA',
        'i18n' : stateProps.i18n.Tabs.exampleOptionATab

      },
      {
        'onClick' : dispatchProps.goToExampleOptionB,
        'key' : 'ExampleOptionB',
        'i18n' : stateProps.i18n.Tabs.exampleOptionBTab
      }
    ]
  }, stateProps)
}
```

The problem is when I open my Container it brings to me this warning:

[image]

And my `DeyailsContainer` component is this one:

```
let DetailsContainer =  ({
    tabs,
    rightIcons,
    activeTab,
    children
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Tabs tabs={tabs} rightIcons={rightIcons} activeTab={activeTab}/>
            <div className="app-wrapper">
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to passing your i18n prop directly into a `<div i18n="whatever" />` somewhere.

My guess is it's inside your DetailsContainer component. If you're spreading all of the props your component receives into the div like this `<div {...props} />`, that will definitely do it.

React has warnings now when you try to pass some type of prop that isn't a standard attribute for a DOM element. If you need the i18n as an attribute for a reason like this... [HTML tags in i18next translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038458/html-tags-in-i18next-translation), you'll want to change that to data-i18n as the prop.

Comment: I updated the information to show you my `DetailsContainer` it seems that is not in there.

Comment: Did you figure it out? It could be in your Tabs component. That component looks familiar actually. If you happen to be using the react-foundation components library, that's where the problem is. Unfortunately, they're passing invalid props into a lot of their elements. I ended up not using them.

Comment: I did not figure it out yet. But I a using my own `Tabs` Component:

https://gist.github.com/FMCalisto/300e524215e530060ac31950b62c3f9f