# Escape special characters in i18next

Tags: node.js, i18next

So i have this variable that will consist in something like '<123456789>'

and then i have this:

```
 var vocab = mm('responses.positive', {
        lngs:LANG,
        target: User.tag,
        amount: r * multiplier,
        icon: iconFile
    })
```

this will make `vocab` return `Message &lt;123456789&gt;`

is there something i can do to avoid it to parse symbols this way?
I've tried escaping in the string that it will return, but it does not work. even if it did work, i also have the problem that i have a `>` occurring **inside** the variable.

A less elegant solution would be editing the string to esape every character, but then i'd need to know exactly which of them i receive, which renders this solution unfeasible.

I've already seen some solutions inserted into HTML, but since i am not using any HTML interface here, the solution would have to be on the JS itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038458/html-tags-in-i18next-translation

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set `escapeValue` to false:

```
i18n.t("key", { 'interpolation': {'escapeValue': false} })
```

Comment: Is there a way to set that param on the whole app ? Since I am in react native, escaping HTMl doesn't make sense in this kind of project

Answer (score 11):

Another way to toggle escaping off is by putting `-` before the key:

```
"keyUnescaped": "dangerous {{- myVar}}"
```

More information: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation.