# How to escape curly braces in Angular's $localize function?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n, angular-localize

If i try to translate the following text:

```
{example}
```

like this:

```
$localize`{example}`
```

The text will disappear in the translated build.

Is there a way to escape the curly braces?

Comment: I think this article can help you=) <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230102/escape-special-characters-in-i18next

Comment: Sorry but this information is not helpful. Your link is about i18next while i am asking about Angular's built-in $localize function. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Havent used angular since 8, but if you are using the bash shell (assumption due to the `$` in question), you should  be escaping the braces with `\{  \}` or `'{ }'` as well. The escapes will disappear by the time it gets to Angular. Otherwise the shell will be expanding / evaluating any special characters `?`, `*`, `,`, `#`, etc. and changing the entire string as a result. Any shell will behave similarly. Chances are that angular isn't even recieving the same tokens you are sending. Single quotes ensure that the shell is blind to what is inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing:

```
       $localize`${'{'}example}`
```

Comment: As you can see in the example, mine does not have a dollar sign ($) in front of the curly braces. This issue is about something else that happens in the build process when building an other language. It uses the curly braces to replace stuff. But i can't find how to escape it.

Comment: Check out this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38569 - $localize`hello {world}` gets escaped with $localize`hello ${'{'}world}` in this comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38569#issuecomment-680041713

Comment: You're right, this is exactly the issue i was talking about. Marked as correct!