# Angular 8: Error when trying to generate translation files

Tags: angular, npm, angular-i18n

I'm in the process of developing my first translatable Angular 8 app using the new i18n module.

I have already added translation keys everywhere in my application's templates using either the i18n or i18n-placeholder attributes.

However, when I try to run the "ng xi18n" command, I just get the error

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

with not other debug output. I have tried adding arguments such as --verbose, -verbose or -v already, but these don't seem to work on `ng xi18n`.

I am using Angular 8.2.5 and Angular CLI 8.3.3 on macOS High Sierra and my application builds just fine using both `ng serve` and `ng build`

Has anyone experienced this issue before and can help or can at least provide a way to debug this?

Comment: Please share the code you used. The error could indicate of colliding component variable and template variable.

Comment: The only things I've used so far are definitions like
`i18n="@@element-inner-html"` and `i18n-placeholder="@@placeholder-for-field"` while still specifying both either the normal placeholder value and untranslated content.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038458/html-tags-in-i18next-translation)?

Comment: Ok, so now I know that that is the framework that powers the Angular translations, however, all I need right now is a way to debug the ng xi18n command, which there doesn't seem to be.