# i18n in html file inside react project

Tags: html, reactjs, react-i18next

I'm trying to translate pre created react application. I decided to use i18n and I didn't have problem with adding translation to regular .tsx files, but later I found some text to translate in raw html files. Is it possible to use i18n in this type of files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML tags in i18next translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038458/html-tags-in-i18next-translation)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.